# What does ‘don't even’ mean in the dialogue?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

I saw a picture on a bag, and there is a conversation between two cartoon figures. One said,"*It wasn't me*", and the other one said, "*Don't even*".

So what is the meaning of ***Don't even*** here in this dialogue?

Answer (score 2):

In your usage

> Don't even

is being used as short for

> Don't even *go there*

meaning "*don't even* try to explain your way out of this"

Comment: I agree that it is short for "Don't even go there," but surely the implied meaning depends on the context?

Comment: The context is pretty clear, by saying "It wasn't me", the implication is that they are trying to explain it wasn't them, since the only reason to say "it wasn't me" would be because someone is causing you of *something*.  However, we don't know what they are being accused of.

Comment: @Peter, Hmm. But suppose what you say is true, is <don't even> even a natural phrase to use then?

Comment: I think so, at least it has become one... https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t+even+think+about+parking+here&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidu52fvuHVAhXErVQKHT1lCJYQ_AUICigB&biw=1388&bih=775

Answer (score 1):

To add to Peter's answer, "don't even go there" could also mean "Don't even deny it was you" or "Don't even bring that up" (whatever cartoon #1 denied doing).

"Don't even" is a colloquial saying, and the grammar on "even" used this way is a little rough. Essentially when you hear "even" used liked this, it's being used for emphasis.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-not-even

Comment: "rough" meaning?